# Texts converted automatically to Uppercase

Tags: sapui5

All texts of my application are getting converted automatically to uppercase. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using an *SAPGW/ABAP OData service*, right? What control are you using, `sap.m.Text`, `sap.m.Input`,...?

In case of *SAPGW/ABAP OData*, did you check the metadata for the display-format annotation, is the value *UpperCase*? If yes, then that’s the reason why your texts are displayed as upper case. You can disable this by changing or removing the annotation. It depends on how the OData service was created to remove the annotation. I assume that your property is based on an ABAP type etc which is not configured as case sensitive on ABAP side and thus the SAPGW sets the annotation to upper cases.